# how to change default generated style in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

in MVC when we want add new controller class in the scaffolding option we can choose template that generate views and etc .

i want to know how can i have a custom template  ?

i want to add some new  view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [MVCScaffolding](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/), it is a more powerful scaffolding engine than supports customizing the templates and creating custom scaffolders.

I don't know of a way to do it with the default scaffolder.